# Hadoop: can you use a pair of values as "Key"?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to analyze a big crimes statistics data set, the file is about 2 GB in CSV format. There are about 20 columns, but I am interested in only a subset of it: Crime_Type and Crime_in_Year. For example, the crime type "burglary", it happens from 2001 through 2013, every year. I want to have a result that counts the occurrences of burglary in each year.

So I am thinking of having a key , and the value will be the sum of its occurrence in year 2003. Is it possible to have a pair of value as key in hadoop/mapreduce?

Answer (score 2):

A `Key` can be anything so long as it implements `Writable`. You could write your own custom key pretty easily as shown [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html).

So borrowing from the documentation, one implementation might be

```
public class CrimeWritable implements Writable {    
       private int year;
       private String type;

       public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
         out.writeInt(year);
         out.writeBytes(type);
       }

       public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
         year = in.readInt();
         type = in.readBytes();
       }

       public static CrimeWritable read(DataInput in) throws IOException {
         CrimeWritable w = new CrimeWritable();
         w.readFields(in);
         return w;
       }
     }
```

On a related note, you might want to consider using a higher level abstraction than map-reduce like [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/) or [Apache Spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/).

Comment: Just a small comment to your answer: `WritableComparables can be compared to each other, typically via Comparators. Any type which is to be used as a key in the Hadoop Map-Reduce framework should implement this interface.` (copy paste) So a key has to be comparable as well!

Comment: Just to be clear, that's WritableComparable, not Writable. But you're right, it is important to implement WritableComparable for keys. I was more focused on the "composite key" aspect of the question. Thank you for providing important additional information.  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html

Answer (score 0):

One possible pair is: 
In the `map()` function generate the key value pair as

(Crime_Year CrimeType, value)
Set the key as "Crime_Year Burglary" and let the value be an integer value. 
This actually means that in a given dataset check if the crime type is "burglary" then concat the Crime_Year with it and set this String as the key, and let the value be the integer 1.

In the `reduce()` sum up all the values with the same keys.

**Example:**
`map()` output:

 <2001 burglary, 1>

<2001 burglary, 1>

<2002 burglary, 1>

<2003 burglary, 1>

`reduce()` output (Sum up the values of the same keys):

<2001 burglary, 2>

<2002 burglary, 1>

<2003 burglary, 1>

In the end you would get the total no. of crimes yearwise.